# ok() permanently generates 501 Not Implemented - play 2.2.1

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

Help me, please, to figure out why my ok() permanently generates HTTP 501 Not Implemented.

No matter what I do, I always end up with a play's TODO page. Complete clone of the same action in the same project works just fine and returns "200 OK" with rendered template.

All action and routes set properly. Compiler gives no errors.

Here is the code:

1. Action

   ```
   public class UserController extends Controller {

       static Form<User> userRegisterForm = form(User.class);  

       public static Result userRegForm() {
           return ok(userRegister.render(userRegisterForm));
       }

   }
   ```
2. Route

   ```
   GET     /register   controllers.UserController.userRegForm()
   ```

UPD:
This combination returns "501 Not Implemented" too and no redirect is followed after:

```
public static Result userRegForm() {
    return redirect( "/" );
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to see the code of the action.

Comment: I've just added it. All is pretty standard. But what is strange: absolutely the same code, just with another method names and for different route and different template, works just fine.

Comment: Usual question: have you tried "play clean compile" ?

Comment: Yes, and none of that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. Thanks to Marius: http://www.mariussoutier.com/blog/2012/12/10/playframework-routes-part-1-basics/

Now I know - play routes may be quite tricky.

Here is my routes file:

```
  # Routes
  # This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
  # ~~~~

  # Home page
  GET     /                       controllers.Application.index()

  # Login and Logout
  GET     /login                  controllers.Application.login()
  POST    /login                  controllers.Application.authenticate()
  GET     /logout                 controllers.Application.logout()

  # Adding new task
  GET     /newtask                controllers.TaskController.taskNewForm()
  POST    /newtask                controllers.TaskController.taskAdd()

  # Tasks
  GET     /:category              controllers.TaskController.taskList(category)
  GET     /:category/:taskId      controllers.TaskController.taskDetails(category, taskId: Long)

  # User
  GET     /register               controllers.UserController.userForm()
  POST    /register               controllers.UserController.userNewSave()

  # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
  GET     /assets/*file           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

So all routes after those two GETs for `/:category` and `/:category/:taskId` were overridden.

The fix was just to nest `/:category` as a subfolder. This worked out:

```
  GET     /Category/:category              controllers.TaskController.taskList(category)
  GET     /Category/:category/:taskId      controllers.TaskController.taskDetails(category, taskId: Long)
```